# Get part of URL after ~

Tags: php, uri

For example, my URL is `http://example.tld/~2g`. I want to get the data after the `~` (`2g` here).

How can I do this? I tried

```
$visitlink = explode("~", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you get for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: The result of explode is an array, to you need to get the right element from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this:

```
$visitlink = explode("~",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],2);
$aftertilde = $visitlink[1];
```

Comment: Yep, that work, will mark as answer as soon as I can (At least after 15 min of asking question as stackoverflow rule). This was exactly what i wanted.

Comment: As the `REQUEST_URI` is user-supplied you might want to provide a default value in case there is no `~`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11277659/367456

Comment: That's not a problem, this is a part of another function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$visitlink = preg_replace('/^[^~]+~(.*)$/', '$1', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

The `^[^~]+~` part of RegEx will match everything until a `~` is encountered. `(.*)` will match everything after tilde. `$1` is used to back-reference what is matched by `(.*)`.

Comment: Also captures the `~`, which isn't the result being asked for ;)

Comment: It doesn't capture the ~, since it replaces everything with just what is after the tilde. :)

Comment: No, it replaces everything up to but not including the `~`

Comment: On a re-reading you're right, thought I'd put that second ~ in there already :) Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

`list($before, $after) = explode("~", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);`

This should work. I'm not sure if the list function is deprecated.

Comment: `list()` is not a function, it is a language construct: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php .

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have always noticed that `list` works a bit differently than most function notation. Kind of strange to assign values in a parameter to the left of the equal sign. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No problem, also `list()` could be a function if there would be a possibility to apply reflection on variables. Since variables do not know their names, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To get most out of the [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function, tell PHP to only split at the first `~` (by telling *2*). The `list` construct helps to directly assign the return value ([Demo](http://codepad.org/cM0RimiR)):

```
list(, $visitlink) = explode("~", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
```

If you are not sure if the value exists at all, you might want to provide a default value:

```
list(, $visitlink) = explode("~", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2) + array(1 => NULL); 
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes use of the [*array union operator*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

Alternatively: You have a simple pattern here, take everything after the first `~`:

```
sscanf($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "%*[^~]~%s", $data);
```

This example uses the [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) function suitable for simple string searches/pattern, the result is assigned to the `$data` variable here. [Demo](http://codepad.org/sumS744p).